dynamodb ConditionExpression is not working as expected
I would like to insert record in dynamodb only if the attribute value doesnt exist already.
     try:
        NewsTable.put_item(
            Item={
                "PK": "intentional_id_to_check_failing_of_ConditionExpression",
                "SK": f"news#id#{uuid.uuid4().hex}",
                "model_type": "TEST_MODEL",
                "title": "dummy_title_1",
                "timestamp": Decimal(str(datetime.now().timestamp())),
            },
            ConditionExpression="attribute_not_exists(PK)",
        )
    except resource.meta.client.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException as e:
        print(e)


Above what I am trying to do is, to insert only if the PK doesn't exists already.
I checked this answer and I found that above should work How do I conditionally insert an item into a dynamodb table using boto3
Help me understand what I am missing if I have got something wrong.
IDEALLY-> I want to insert only if title of the record doesn't already exist
Just leaving with PK for now is because it did work in the past and now not working.

More code I have tried:


    pk = "intentional_id_to_check_failing_of_ConditionExpression"
    try:
        NewsTable.put_item(
            Item={
                "PK": pk,
                "SK": f"news#id#{uuid.uuid4().hex}",
                "model_type": "TEST_MODEL",
                "title": "dummy_title_1",
                "timestamp": Decimal(str(datetime.now().timestamp())),
            },
            ConditionExpression=Attr("PK").ne(pk),
        )
    except resource.meta.client.exceptions.ConditionalCheckFailedException as e:
        print(e)



here i am using Attr with not equal condition

Your code is right, however I think your understanding of how conditions work is not correct...
Essentially when you put a condition that the item does not exist, you only evaluate the item that your currently trying to insert (PK, SK).
No other item will be evaluated.

can you add example of what the correct code should be or some references?

i dont understand this: ===>
"you only evaluate the item that your currently trying to insert (PK, SK)."
i have a record that has the PK with some value, my goal is to not insert if it already exists in the table.

If you have an item (1,1) and you try to put an item (1,2) with a condition that (1) does not exist, it will only check if (1,2) exists or not, (1,1) will never be evaluated.
